# Get angular directive by name

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I know that we can get services from `$injector` by their name. Is it possible to somehow get the directive/component object from the dependency injector?

For example, if I wanted to write a service that can take a component's name, retrieve the component and do something with retrieved properties, how would I be able to retrieve the component by its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get services from `$injector` because there is only a single instance of each service in the system: *they are singletons*.

On the other hand, *Directives/components* have multiple instances for each time they show up on the page. Moreover, they cannot be injected as they are always created and bound to HTML.

Comment: How the `ng-controller` directive works? It seems to take a name of a controller constructor function to use. Similarly, how is any directive able to take the name of the controller and resolve it to the backing function?

Comment: For controllers there is a [$controller](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/docs/api/ng/service/$controller) service that you can use to create instances of controllers.

Comment: I would love it if it were possible to get the object used for instantiation instead of the instance. I'll accept the answer as is.